# $\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$ of root and ratio test sequences of a series (Rudin)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

$\lim \sup$ and $\lim \inf$ of root and ratio test sequences of a series (Rudin)

[image]
[image]

I understand that:

$$(1) \qquad \{\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\} = \{\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{2^2},\frac{2^2}{3^2},\frac{3^2}{2^3},...\} = \{\frac{2^n}{3^n}, \frac{3^n}{2^{n+1}}\}$$

$$(2) \qquad \{\sqrt[n]{a_n}\} = \{\sqrt[1]{1/2},\sqrt[2]{1/3},\sqrt[3]{1/2^2},\sqrt[4]{1/3^2},...\} = \{\sqrt[2n-1]{\frac{1}{2^n}}, \sqrt[2n]{\frac{1}{3^n}}\}$$

Then there are two subsequences of $(1)$ and $(2)$, each of which will lead to $\lim \sup$ or $\lim \inf$ for each sequence.

Questions:
1- Is my understanding right?
2- Why $\lim \sup \ (2)=\lim \sqrt[2n]{\frac{1}{2^n}}$ while $\{\sqrt[2n]{\frac{1}{2^n}}\}$ is not a subsequence of $(2)$?
3- Does $(1)$ or $(2)$ has only two subsequences?
4- Does $(1)$ or $(2)$ has only two subsequential limits?
5- Is there an informal way to choose the subsequence whose limit is $\lim \sup/\inf$ of a sequence, or should I consider every possible subsequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is right.

The author just decided to write the limit in a way he likes, but it's not coming directly from the sequence; personally, I think it makes no sense to write it like that. To calculate the limit of the subsequence, 
$$
(a_{2n-1})^{1/(2n-1)}=(2^{-n})^{1/(2n-1)}=e^{-\frac{n}{2n-1}\,\log 2}\to e^{-\frac12\,\log 2}=2^{-1/2}=\frac1{\sqrt2}.
$$

There are only two subsequential limits in this case, because the distance between $2^{-n/(2n-1)}$ and $3^{-1/2}$ cannot be small for large $n$.

There is no canonical recipe in general. These example works nicely because there are only two subsequences to choose from.

Comment: "personally, I think it makes no sense to write it like that" Sorry but what exactly "makes no sense" here?

Comment: Then, how can I calculate $\lim 2^{\frac{-n}{2n-1}}$?

Comment: @Did: writing the liminf as the limit of a sequence that is not a subsequence.

Comment: @AbduMagdy: I have edited that into the answer.

Comment: Well, $a_{2n-1}=1/2^n$ and $a_{2n}=1/3^n$ hence $a_{2n-1}^{1/(2n-1)}=(1/2^n)^{1/(2n-1)}$ and $a_{2n}^{1/2n}=1/3^{1/2}$. Are you complaining because R. replaced $(1/2^n)^{1/(2n-1)}$ by $(1/2^n)^{1/(2n)}$? Saying that "it makes no sense" is slightly too strong (hence, misleading), if you ask me.

Comment: I don't think it's misleading. The author wrote that the liminf is $\lim 2^{-n/2n}=1/\sqrt2$. Writing instead that the liminf is $1/\sqrt2$ gives exactly the same amount of information. No one does the following steps to calculate the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1/2^n)^{1/(2n-1)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1/2^n)^{1/2n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}1/2^{1/2},$$ because the justification of the first equality is no simpler than just calculating the limit directly.

Comment: It would make more sense to only use the phrase "it makes no sense" when indeed "it" makes no sense. Otherwise, one takes the risk of using it when "it" does make sense, hence, when it does not make sense to use the phrase. Just common sense. (Unrelated: Omitting @ where it is needed makes... well, no sense.)

Comment: Thanks so much :)

Comment: @Did: what you say makes sense. But I will leave my "it makes no sense" because I wrote that "it makes no sense *to write it like that*". So I sense that it is clear that the "it" that makes no sense is "to write it like that". Do I make sense?  ;)

Comment: Not excessively, because to declare that a small imprecision "makes no sense" is so excessive that it nearly makes no sense.